# Rolled back from Catalina back to Mojave but I had two drives one for boot and other for saved files, realised old files are still around

Tags: filesystem, user-account, storage, downgrade

I rolled back from Catalina to Mojave because I was having issues, it was my first time to do so and foolishly didn't use Time Machine.

I have two SSDs, one for boot and the other for my files, and I realise that my files are still on the other drive but I can no longer access them, the folders have the red stop sign.

Is there a way to access the files and use those folders again as my main user folder?

Comment: How did you "roll back" to Mojave? Wipe the boot drive and a clean install of Mojave? What's the content of the data SSD? One user folder containing the usual folders (Movies/Pictures etc.) or the "Users" folder containing your main user folder?

Comment: I wiped the boot drive and did a clean install of Mojave, I set my Users folder to the data SSD with all the movies, pictures, downloads, etc. ,

Comment: Still unclear: the "Users" folder is a default "system" folder, usually containing one or more user folders (e.g. adminisa, isa etc). Each "user" folder contains the whole set of default folders (Movies/Pictures etc.) and probably some custom-made folders like Development, Business, Private etc.. Please add a screenshot of the content of the Data SSD showing the hierarchy of the folders.

Comment: Here's the screenshot: https://imgur.com/jihaYVH, does that help?

Comment: Still unclear: We need the whole path to answer your question properly e.g /Volumes/Data/Users/isa/Pictures (etc) **or** /Volumes/Data/isa/Pictures (etc). **or** /Volumes/Data/Pictures (etc). Data is the name of an example volume. In the different scenarios either /Users/isa or isa or the volume itself is your user folder.

Comment: Ah... I see so it's something like this? "/Volumes/Mac\ Storage/isa/Movies"

Comment: Exactly. So it's obviously the 2nd example in my previous comment...

Answer (score 1):

It's an easy task to make your old (Catalina) user folder accesible again. I don't recommend to use it as your (Mojave) user folder though.

Upgrading from Mojave to Catalina not only changes system files and apps but also may have changed some content of your user folder. After replacing iTunes and its library with the new triplicitas Music, TV and Podcast and their libraries, your old Mojave iTunes won't work anymore. Other files may have been "upgraded" too e.g. preferences files, Mail data folder etc.

You probably want to move your current user folder (Mojave) to *Mac Storage* again.

I assume that you didn't change your macOS shortname (=isa).

1. Rename the old isa (Catalina) folder:

   ```
   sudo mv /Volumes/Mac\ Storage/isa /Volumes/Mac\ Storage/isa-catalina
   ```
2. Change file and folder permissions of isa-catalina to your current user and group id:

   ```
   sudo chown -R `id -u`:`id -g` /Volumes/Mac\ Storage/isa-catalina
   ```
3. Move your current user folder /Users/isa to /Volumes/Mac\ Storage

   You probably followed one of several how-tos (e.g. [Move Your Mac's Home Folder to a New Location](https://www.lifewire.com/move-macs-home-folder-new-location-2260157))
4. Move personal files and folders from isa-catalina to isa. As mentioned earlier I don't recommend to move content of isa-catalina/Library/... to isa/Library/... except prefs and config files of non-Apple apps.

   To get your ("Catalina") music/podcast/photo/movie files back you have to dig into the respective folders and *.library files. Catalina's *Photos Library.photolibrary* is probably incompatible with Mojave's Photo.app.

Comment: A related question but -- i also found another applications folder with my old applications in it -- do i just drag them to the current. You mentioned that i shouldn't touch the library except for non apple apps -- so i assume it's possible?

Comment: @Isa It depends on the app. It's no problem to copy a self-containing app (eg BBEdit or DaisyDisk). Other apps like Photoshop or VirtualBox (apps which are installed by an installer app or are delivered as pkg files) have to be installed freshly. Besides the app itself a lot of files have to be installed to specific places in the file system (eg fonts in the Fonts folder/*.frameworks in the Frameworks folder/support files in the Application Support folder). If you just copy such an app to /Applications all other necessary files are missing & it wouldn't work properly or fail to launch at all.

Comment: Got it, this answers my question, especially the Photoshop part, thanks again, you've been a real help.

Comment: @Isa You **can** move the folder /Volumes/Mac\ Storage/isa-catalina/Library/Application\ Support/Adobe to the respective destination in /Volumes/Mac\ Storage/isa. It typically contains user-made presets or AdobeID related (=personal) stuff. But you still have to install Adobe PS because a lot of stuff is installed to /Library/Application\ Support/Adobe (which isn't a "personal" folder).